# Streaming algorithm for polynomial fitting data?

Tags: polynomials, approximation

The specific problem I'm trying to solve is: $$h_k(x, n) = \left(\frac{\alpha}{n} + 1 - \alpha\right) \sum_{i=0}^{k} c_ix^i.$$

Given $k$ and a stream of tuples $(x, n, h_k(x, n))$ (where the $x$'s and $n$'s are not necessarily distinct), find an $\alpha$ and $c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_k$ that approximate $h_k$. The simplest solutions to fitting such a curve would be to use something like least squares, but that would require storing all tuples and computing the approximation at the end.

Is there a way to keep a rolling approximation of the coefficients and $\alpha$, so that the approximation can be updated as new tuples come in, without needing to store all previous tuples?

Comment: Perhaps look at "real time" algorithms. Perhaps something akin to a Kalman filter is really what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this question while researching something similar. Perhaps this will be of use : http://erikerlandson.github.io/blog/2012/07/05/deriving-an-incremental-form-of-the-polynomial-regression-equations/

The regression is $$\left( \begin{array} {c}
a_0 \\
a_1 \\
\vdots \\
a_m \\
\end{array} \right)
=
\left( \begin{array} {cccc}
n & \Sigma x & \cdots & \Sigma x^m \\
\Sigma x & \Sigma x^2 & \cdots & \Sigma x^{m+1} \\
\vdots & & \ddots & \vdots \\
\Sigma x^m & \Sigma x^{m+1} & \cdots & \Sigma x^{2 m} \\
\end{array} \right)
^ {-1}
\left( \begin{array} {c}
\Sigma y \\
\Sigma x y \\
\vdots \\
\Sigma x^m y \\
\end{array} \right)$$

so you need to store $\Theta(k^2)$ values for incremental calculation.